# mySQL (left join?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables which I want to query from.

The first table (lets call it `users`) has these columns: `id` and `name`.

The second table (lets call it `transactions`) has these columns: `user_id`, `amount` and `timestamp`.

How do I find out the latest timestamp in `transactions` for each user in the `users` table?

EDIT:

Thanks for all your answers so far! Really appreciate it. How about, if I want to select users with the latest timestamp greater than a certain value?

Comment: This looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820042/max-date-for-each-worker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*,MAX(t.timestamp) latest_timestamp
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.user_id=u.id
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Should be what you're looking for. This query should select the latest transaction timestamp for each user.

Comment: Except this won't work, since all of the columns in users are not specified in the GROUP BY clause.  :(

Comment: I'm assuming that each user has a unique user id. It may even be possible for different users to have the same name, so I didn't include that field in my group by.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. (: Any idea why when I add `WHILE latest_timestamp > xxxxxxxxx`, it doesn't return the expected rows?

Comment: One other thing, my query won't include users who have no transactions. Did you need those users included in the result set? To answer your question, it's WHERE, not WHILE. `... WHERE latest_timestamp > xxxxx`

Comment: Nop, I don't need users who have no transactions. Oh yep, and I meant `WHERE` but it doesn't work that way too.

Comment: Oh, actually since the filter relies on the aggregate function of the GROUP BY clause, you need to use HAVING rather than WHERE. `... HAVING latest_timestamp>xxxxxx`

Comment: @StuartAinsworth actually, in mysql, you can have columns that arent in group by or aggregate functions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html
it just uses any value

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
     id,
     name,
     max(timestamp) 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN transactions 
ON users.id = transactions.user_id
GROUP BY id,name
```

that should give you te greatest timestamp for every user in the users table

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Users.name,MAX(T.timestamp) As LastTimeStamp
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN Transactions as T ON Users.user_id=T.user_id    
GROUP BY Users.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will do more than what you asked, but this is just in case your next question would be "what if I also wanted to know the amount that belongs to the maximum timestamp?":

```
SELECT id, name, t.`timestamp`, amount
FROM (SELECT id, name, MAX(`timestamp`) AS `timestamp`
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN transactions t ON t.user_id=u.id
    GROUP BY id, name
) AS maxt
INNER JOIN transactions t 
ON t.user_id = maxt.id AND t.`timestamp` = maxt.`timestamp`
```